# Service to Service Communication with Keycloak Gatekeeper Active for RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, rbac

I am using ProxyInjector to inject keycloak-gatekeeper into any pod I want to restrict access to.  It works in that I can restrict access, and users that should have access can access it just fine after they login to keycloak.

But how can I let other 'dumb' (ones that don't have their own auth support) kubernetes services access it?  It currently denies them because they aren't logged in, but it is necessary for these services to talk to each other.  Either by letting them bypass the authentication, or by attaching a service account or something to their requests.

Edit:

After further investigation, I found out I can access it by adding another port to the service as follows:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: testapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: testapp
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: testapp-backend
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8080
```

By having the ingress point to port 8080, it locks out the app for those who try to access it outside the cluster.  I have the other internal services pointing to testapp:8081, which connects.

But this is just a workaround, as any other service on kubernetes could attempt to connect to `testapp:8081` and succeed without authentication, right?

Comment: Hi it's not clear what you are trying to do. 
I am not sure this approach is right.
Please follow [this article](https://medium.com/@vcorreaniche/securing-serverless-services-in-kubernetes-with-keycloak-gatekeeper-6d07583e7382)

Comment: @Hanx Inside my LAN, I have the DNS entries for subdomains pointed to the kubernetes ingress controller.  I can also access services that aren't hosted from k8s from their domain name because of internal dns resolution. Outside my LAN, 80/443 is forwarded to the kubernetes ingress controller.  But I cannot access non-k8s services because it all gets forwarded to the ingress controller.  So I wanted to proxy any traffic for that host from the ingress controller to the other non-k8s application.